# WPF XAML serialize/deserialize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization

my application is basically taking one WPF Canvas containing other controls and serialize it to an XML file and then deserialize it to display the serialized data or a previously saved one. The serialization/deserialization is working fine everything is saved and restored back. The issue is that after deserialization if I try to change an image source with the bellow code it doesn't work:

```
testLogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.FileName));
```

The Image is referrenced in the XAML as bellow:

```
<Canvas Name="mainCanva" Margin="0,0,12,0" Width="1729" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF009B80" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1729" Height="150">
          <Grid Margin="0" Background="White" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Uid="">
               <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,28,0,57">
                   <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="testLogo" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="317" Source="file:///C:/Users/logo.jpg" />
               </Grid>
          </Grid>
     </Border>
</Canvas>
```

The Deserialization code is as bellow:

```
Canvas canvas = DeSerializeXAML(appPath + "\\tmp\\mainCanva.xml") as Canvas;
mainCanva.Children.Clear();

while (canvas.Children.Count > 0)
{
       UIElement obj = canvas.Children[0]; 
       canvas.Children.Remove(obj); 
       mainCanva.Children.Add(obj); // Add to canvas
}
```

Another point to note is that I tried to find out what was happening using Snoop, after Deserialization Snoop is also unable to change the image source although if I reconnect Snoop to the app by drag and dropping the crosshair Snoop is now able to change the Image source. The 'old' Snoop window can see the image source being updated from the testLogo.Source = command. WPF inspector doesn't have this issue it is immediately updating itself when the deserialization is happening. My guess is that there is something wrong with the visual tree ... and as WPF can do it I think it can be sorted.

Thanks for the help guys.

As requested the Serialize/Deserialize functions:

```
public static void SerializeToXAML(UIElement element, string filename)
    {
        string strXAML = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(element);

        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter streamwriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                streamwriter.Write(strXAML);
            }
        }
    }

    public static UIElement DeSerializeXAML(string filename)
    {
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            return System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(fs) as UIElement;
        }
    }
```

Comment: file in this line `testLogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.FileName));` , if you open the file in window's `ImageViewer`, what u see ? , and here : `Canvas canvas = DeSerializeXAML(appPath + "\\tmp\\mainCanva.xml") as Canvas;` is `canvas` null ?

Comment: How is your DeSerializeXAML method implemented!?

Comment: The file is showing just fine and the canvas is not null as everything is getting displayed properly after deserialization. Serialization/Deserialization functions posted in the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your variable reference.

When you call mainCanva.Children.Clear(), it removes all the children including testLogo. Your variable testLogo will still be pointing at the original testLogo object even though it's not part of the UI anymore.

Try this:

```
Canvas canvas = DeSerializeXAML(appPath + "\\tmp\\mainCanva.xml") as Canvas;
mainCanva.Children.Clear();

while (canvas.Children.Count > 0)
{
       UIElement obj = canvas.Children[0]; 
       canvas.Children.Remove(obj); 
       mainCanva.Children.Add(obj); // Add to canvas
}
testLogo = mainCanva.FindName("testLogo") as Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Application resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="testLogo" >file:///C:/Users/test_B&amp;W.png</BitmapImage>
</Application.Resources>
```

then in the code:

```
Resources["AVItestLogoic"] = ...
```

This way no matter what happens to the Visual Tree, the application resource always point to the right item